# Which bitrates does ffmpeg support for AAC-LC encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

Which bitrates are supported by ffmpeg for AAC-LC encoding?

I want to encode 44.1kHz,16 Bit Mono Audio. The framesize is set to 1024. But only some bitrates seem to be support, if I set the bitrate to 320 it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 44.1 kHz mono with 1024-sample frames, AAC-LC's maximum bitrate is:

> (6144 bits/block ÷ 1024 samples/block) × 44100 samples/sec × 1 channel = 264.6 kbit/s

FFmpeg supports [4 different AAC-LC encoders](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).  The best quality can be obtained using libfdk_aac, which supports all the way up to the maximum bitrate.

See also [Recommended sampling rate and bitrate combinations](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC#Recommended_Sampling_Rate_and_Bitrate_Combinations).